# Causes of Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

I have this error **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** in my JS code and I want to know which are the causes for this error.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[Symbol.replace]                    @ (program):405
replace                             @ (program):134
n.extend.camelCase                  @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2
R                                   @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3
n.extend._data                      @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3
n.extend.queue                      @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3
n.extend.dequeue                    @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3
(anonymous function)                @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4
n.extend.each                       @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2
n.fn.n.each                         @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2
n.fn.extend.stop                    @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4
```

Comment: Please share your recursion code if there is any

Comment: I already editted my question.

Comment: share your replace function aswell

Comment: I found it. The error is in niceScroll library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you post your code here.

There could be various reasons,

1. You can also get this error when you have an infinite loop. Make sure that you don't have any unending, recursive self references.
2. You are creating thousands of HTML elements, or binding thousands of events
3. Never ending, recursion of function
4. Never ending, event recursion or fire of custom event handlers

Also, You might get more information about where these exception occurred in your chrome or firefox debugger, you can share that code where this error occurred and we could help you out.

Comment: I already editted my question with code of exception.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused because you have an **infinite recursion** somewhere

You can easily replicate this with

```
(f=> f(f)) (f=> f(f))

// Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Unless you post your code, it's impossible for us to give you more specific help

Comment: I have some parts of my that, unfortunately, **sometimes** give this error. I only want to try understand which it is the problem.

Comment: I already editted my question with code of exception.